# opentherm in parallel with on/off thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I have a new Honeywell Lyric T6, in the living room, 20V 2-wired with the 230VAC control box near central heater. There is a parallel on/off thermostat, that kicks in if the house gets too cold when a fireplace in the living room is on. Will the dual setup still work as before or will the on/off damage the controller by the 20V shortcut? When the secondary thermostat goes On, the circuit is closed and the T6 shuts off (evidently). I tested it briefly, when the secondary thermostat is Open again, the T6 comes back online but I don't trust it. The secondary thermostat is also a Honeywell (round, On/Off). Is the 20V shortcut limited (by a resistor)?

Comment: (in case anyone wonders, of course the living room has bimetal radiator thermostats)

Comment: This is the wrong site for questions on the use of consumer products, sorry.

Comment: Can you tell us what make and model your central heater is? And can you make a sketch of how the two thermostats, 230V powersupply and central heater are wired?